# ((System.IO.FileNotFoundException)(the specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) when running a C# console application

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I am getting an error while running a .Net application.

The main problem which I feel is due to the `Oracle.Data.Access`.I made the project build to 32 bit as it had some problem of [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) exception

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Making my project to 32 bit actually solved this Oracle problem, but then the following error is thrown:

> ((System.IO.FileNotFoundException)(the specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I am actually trying to write to a file in the function from where the exception is being thrown.The file location is defined in app.config

Is this error due to 32 or 64 bit as my Windows 7 version is 64 bit and the project is built using 32 bit or something else

Please suggest a possible outcome of this error

Answer (score 0):

The first error suggests the assembly (dll) Oracle.DataAccess is not found in your /BIN folder. If it is there please check the version, your application is expecting version: 2.111.7.20, you might be using another version.

`Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`

The second error might be thrown because the Oracle.DataAcces it is 64-bit and your application is now running in 32-bit.

Comment: I have made the application work in 64 bit only..I am getting the error "System.BadImage Exception-is not a valid win32 application". My Oracle Client is 32 bit only...

Comment: So there is your error. You should have a 64 bit Oracle client. Have a look at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html to see if your client is listed. If it is listed it should be a 64 bit. I expect this is going to solve your issue. Be sure the version is the same version as in your app.config.